# Can one embed the Swift REPL inside macOS or iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, read-eval-print-loop

Basically, like playgrounds or pythonista (for Python). Can one create/allow arbitrary swift code (not known at compile time) to interact with an app, like a plugin or extension?

Comment: Not sure how I missed this in all my searching, but `JavaScriptCore` is available on macOS and iOS and is a full-featured way to create extensions that access internal functions/data. It isn't Swift or Python, but has been native for a long time.

Comment: Looking at the "answers" in that question, I would say that your answer below is more correct. (If it's that convoluted and fragile ( requires disabling SIP, for instance), I would say "No" is more correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can talk to the REPL from within Xcode while paused in your app (running from Xcode) at a breakpoint, but that's as close as you can come.

Comment: Related: Since the Python.framework is only on macOS, I wonder how Pythonista is executing Python (I haven't been able to find a description of the internals).

Comment: They compiled Python for iOS. See http://maverick.inria.fr/~Nicolas.Holzschuch/ios_shell.html